# php echo explode array

Tags: php, html

Sorry but I dont know how to explain my problem but rather I will demonstrate my problem here.

This is what I get when I used print_r()

```
Array ( [0] => 2     [1] => 200 ) 
Array ( [0] => 5000  [1] => 1000 )  
Array ( [0] => 2     [1] => 200 ) 
Array ( [0] => 5000  [1] => 1000 ) 
Array ( [0] => 2     [1] => 200 ) 
Array ( [0] => 5000  [1] => 1000 )  
Array ( [0] => 2     [1] => 200 ) 
Array ( [0] => 5000  [1] => 1000 )  
Array ( [0] => 4     [1] => 300 ) 
Array ( [0] => 10000 [1] => 1500 )  
Array ( [0] => 4     [1] => 300 ) 
Array ( [0] => 10000 [1] => 1500 )  
Array ( [0] => 4     [1] => 300 ) 
Array ( [0] => 10000 [1] => 1500 )  
Array ( [0] => 4     [1] => 300 ) 
Array ( [0] => 10000 [1] => 1500 ) 
Array ( [0] => 3     [1] => 100 ) 
Array ( [0] => 7500  [1] => 500 ) 
Array ( [0] => 3     [1] => 100 ) 
Array ( [0] => 7500  [1] => 500 ) 
Array ( [0] => 3     [1] => 100 ) 
Array ( [0] => 7500  [1] => 500 )  
Array ( [0] => 3     [1] => 100 ) 
Array ( [0] => 7500  [1] => 500 )
```

And this is my code

```
foreach ($supp_dtl_1 as $key => $value) {
    $arr = explode(',',$value->unit_price);
    $arr1 = explode(',',$value->total_amount);
    foreach($arr as $cell){
        foreach($arr1 as $cell1){
            //echo print_r($arr);
            //echo print_r($arr1);
            <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $cell; ?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $cell1; ?>"></td>
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result of the above code

```
2 | 5000 | 2 | 1000 | 200 | 5000 | 200 | 1000 | 4 | 10000 | 4 | 1500 | 300 | 10000 | 300 | 3 | 7500 | 3 | 500 | 100 | 7500 | 100 | 500
2 | 5000 | 2 | 1000 | 200 | 5000 | 200 | 1000 | 4 | 10000 | 4 | 1500 | 300 | 10000 | 300 | 3 | 7500 | 3 | 500 | 100 | 7500 | 100 | 500
```

The Expected output should be something like this

```
2   | 5000 |  3    | 7500   | 4   | 10000
200 | 1000 |  100  | 500    | 300 | 1500
```

This is my data in db and the result of my query.

```
Name    |   unit_price  |   total_amount
j1      |   2           |   5000
j1      |   200         |   1000
j2      |   3           |   7500
j2      |   100         |   500
j3      |   4           |   10000
j3      |   300         |   1500
```

Please see the image [Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZZvr.png)
supp_dtl_1 print_r() [Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6H5x.png)

Expected Output [Click Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srs6K.png)
Database [Click Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUHvk.png)

Comment: by the way, I am using group_concat in my query. That's why Im using explode

Comment: It may be worth looking at your SQL as it would be better to just fetch the right data than try and fix the results.

Comment: This is my data in db and the result of my query. 
Name    |   unit_price  |   total_amount
j1           |   2                |   5000
j1           |   200            |   1000
j2           |   3                |   7500
j2           |   100            |   500
j3           |   4                |   10000
j3           |   300            |   1500

Comment: please see above my updated post. I put there the result of my query

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what exactly you want, but I hope the following code will help.
You don't need to nest your second array with another for loop, instead, you can iterate it under the same loop as the first array with $key.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $cell){
        //echo print_r($arr);
        //echo print_r($arr1[$key]);
        <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $cell; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $arr1[$key]; ?>"></td>
 }
```

Comment: Almost there. But there it duplicates the output.

Comment: I added image in my post. That's the result using your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```php
<?php
foreach ($supp_dtl_1 as $key => $value) {
    $arr = explode(',',$value->unit_price);
    $arr1 = explode(',',$value->total_amount);
    foreach($arr as $key2 => $cell){
        echo '<td><input type="text" value="'.$cell.'"></td>';
        echo '<td><input type="text" value="'.$arr1[$key2].'"></td>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I added image in my post. That's the result using your code.

Comment: If you make a print_r on $supp_dtl_1 before the foreach, whats the result?

Comment: Please see image above. I added there.

Comment: If i hard code the $supp_dtl_1 to be $supp_dtl_1 = array(
  (object) array(
   'unit_price' => 'u1',
   'total_amount' => 't1'
  ),
  (object) array(
   'unit_price' => 'u2',
   'total_amount' => 't2'
  ),
  (object) array(
   'unit_price' => 'u3',
   'total_amount' => 't3'
  )
); it works fine @solomon

Comment: Have you tried using my $supp_dtl_1? as you can see in the image I post.

Comment: Quick question, is $supp_dtl_1 ment to have 3 identical arrays in it? @solomon

Comment: Well that I dont know. Hahaha sorry about that. Please do look in the image I posted above (Expected Output). You can see there what Im trying to achieve

Comment: Alright. Are you able to copy paste the print_r result so i don't make any typos? ;)

Comment: Im sorry its too long

Comment: Out of curiosity. What happens if you change 'foreach ($supp_dtl_1 as $key => $value)' to 'foreach ($supp_dtl_1[0] as $key => $value)' ?

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of how you make $supp_dtl_1?

Comment: Im using codeigniter. My query for supp_dtl_1 goes something like this (SELECT supplier_name, group_concat(unit_price), group_concat(total_amount FROM table_name WHERE id_no = '10' GROUP BY supplier_name) )

Comment: Are you using the built in database library? @solomon

Comment: Since there is more query. Im using something like this. return $data = array('hdr' => $hdr, 'supp_dtl_1' => $supp_dtl_1). This one is in the Model..... And in the Controller, $data['supp_dtl_1']. Then pass it into view ($this->load->view('sample_view',$data);)

Comment: In the model, are you using the built-in codeigniter database library?

Comment: What do you mean by database library? Haha sorry. New here. Well of I am correct, I just used the default set-up

Comment: No worries. In codeigniter there is a config file called database.php. If you configure it and add 'database' to the autoload library config, it makes all the database stuff a lot easier. Then you could for example do `$supp_dtl_1 = $this->db->where('x', 'y')->get('table')->result_array();`. You can of course chain multiple where's.

Comment: Yes that's what I did. But I used ordinary query only.

Comment: Can you add me to your email so we can communicate well? I just need your help Sir.

Comment: Hmm it's really weird why it doesn't work then. Can you paste this in the controller and take a screenshot of it? `echo '<pre>;print_r($supp_dtl_1);exit;`